# date diff, including time

Tags: mysql

I have database table whose structure is as follows:

```
id  int
name varchar(20)
dob  datetime
```

I need to find out those records whose datetime difference is greater than 1 days

I know that datediff() can work, but I also want to include time (Hours, Mins, Seconds) in calculation

Example:
  **2011-02-14 13:05:06** (is one day from **2011-02-15 13:05:06**)
  but
2011-02-14 13:05:06 (is NOT one day from ***2011-02-15 13:04:06***)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [TIME_TO_SEC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec)

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2011-02-14 13:05:06','2011-02-15 13:06:06'))/86400;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare your dates in another way:

```
date1 < date_sub(date2, interval 1 day)
```

this comparison will be true, if the difference between date2 and date1 is more than 1 day

Comment: @Jacob: if `date2` < `date1` that comparison will always return false

Comment: sorry, what I mean to say is OP needs something that returns true if date2 is greater than 1 day less or date2 is greater than 1 day more than date1. This will only catch if date2 is greater than 1 day more than date1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `dob` NOT BETWEEN 
    '2011-02-14 13:05' - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
    AND 
    '2011-02-14 13:05' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,concat(small_date,' ',small_time),concat(big_date,' ',big_time))%24 ,' day ' ,
sec_to_time((TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,concat(small_date,' ',small_time),concat(big_date,' ',big_time))) -(
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,concat(small_date,' ',small_time),concat(big_date,' ',big_time))%24*86400))) `datetimediff`
from tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2011-02-14 13:05:06','2011-02-15 13:06:06'))/86400;
```

**Not every day has 86400 seconds!** So this will return wrong answer twice a year, when summer/winter time changes and day is one hour longer or shorter.