# How to obtain in MySQL previous week with specific date

Tags: mysql

I would like to obtain an export from q MySQL table from table with previous week and specific date. I know that I can select dates over the past 7 days like:

```
...BETWEEN NOW() and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

But for my project, the actual date is: `2013-06-17 23:35`

My aim is to obtain the active user from table between :

```
begin : 2013-06-10 9:00
To    : 2013-06-16 9:00 (previous week Monday to Friday with specific hours )
```

And want to script this. Can you help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: use a dynamic interval based on the [dayofweek()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function. That'd let you figure out what you're on and how far 'away' a particular day of week is from your target date.

Answer (score 0):

Give this answer a look: [date diff, including time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308467/date-diff-including-time)

You'll be using `TIME_TO_SEC`

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec

Answer (score 0):

Why not use TIMESTAMPDIFF like:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2013-06-10 09:00:00','2013-06-16 09:00:00')/24 as hourdiff
```

See examples [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

maybe use mysql variables ?

[MySql variables and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580700/mysql-variables-and-php)

and for the mysql part

[MYSQL how to declare a datetime variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396196/mysql-how-to-declare-a-datetime-variable)

should give more information